# How to use startsWith and endsWith function in SparkR 2.3.0？

Tags: sparkr

I can't understand how to use startsWith and endsWith function in SparkR 2.3.0.
I thought that I could use it like starts_with command of dplyr as below, but an error occurred.
If you'd kindly teach me.

```
> df <- read.df("/hadoop/tmp/iris.csv", "csv", header = "true")
> showDF(select(df, startsWith(columns(df), "Sepal")))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'select' for signature '"SparkDataFrame", "logical"'
```

Answer (score 1):

The startsWith and endsWith functions operate on columns, not on a dataframe.

To do the select you are attempting you can use

```
df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
df_sepal <- select(df, names(df)[grepl("Sepal", names(df))])
```

To use startsWith() you need to pass a column as an argument, as well as the string you are checking. For example,

```
df_v <- filter(df, startsWith(df$Species, "v") == TRUE)
```

will filter for only the rows where Species begins with 'v' (versicolor, virginica)

```
df_a <- filter(df, endsWith(df$Species, "a") == TRUE)
```

will filter for only the rows where Species ends with 'a' (setosa, viginica)